# What permissions do I need to run executable with container on gce

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

What permissions do I need?

I created an instance with the `gcloud compute instance create-with-container` command.

Then, the following was displayed in the log.

```json
Error: Failed to start container: Error response from daemon: 
{\" message \ ": \" OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go: 349: starting container process caused \\\ "exec: \\\\\\\ "./foo\\\\\\\": permission denied \\\ ": unknown \"}
```

./foo is executable.
image is built by google cloud build.

Dockerfile

```
# Use the offical golang image to create a binary.
# This is based on Debian and sets the GOPATH to /go.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/golang
FROM golang:1.15-buster as builder

# Create and change to the app directory.
WORKDIR /app

# Retrieve application dependencies.
# This allows the container build to reuse cached dependencies.
# Expecting to copy go.mod and if present go.sum.
COPY go.* ./
RUN go mod download

# Copy local code to the container image.
COPY . ./

# Build the binary.
RUN go build -mod=readonly -v -o foo

# Use the official Debian slim image for a lean production container.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/debian
# https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds
FROM debian:buster-slim
RUN set -x && apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
    ca-certificates && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Copy the binary to the production image from the builder stage.
COPY --from=builder /app/foo /app/foo

# Run the task on container startup.
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["./foo"]
```

this works fine on cloud run.

Comment: Did you tried with Container Admin role?

Comment: Try changing your Dockerfile to use `ENTRYPOINT` instead of `CMD`.

Comment: Does John advice works for your issue? According to the error message, you may add a line `chmod 755 /app/foo` in Dockerfile to give execute permission.

Comment: thanks to all 3 comments. but it still failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix build command
`go build -o foo`

Original build command generate `foo` directory and output execution file in it.

Comment: This answer does not match the Dockerfile in your question. In your question you have this line: `RUN go build -mod=readonly -v -o foo`. That generates the binary `foo`. Where in your Dockerfile is the `task` directory built to match the details in your answer.

Comment: First point: I'm sorry. That was my mistake and I should have written `go build -o foo`.
Second point: I also thought that the original Dockerfile would generate a binary called foo, but when I built it locally for debugging, the `foo` directory was created. It contained a binary named `project-name` and the source `foo.go`. When I modified the Dockerfile build command to `go build -o foo`, it generated a binary named foo as expected. As a result, the error no longer occurs.